# Find the optimal displacement between 2 sets of colored points

Tags: algorithm, match, mathematical-optimization

I have 2 sets of colored points - A and B. The sets contain about 50 elements. The coordinates `p = (p_x, p_y)` of a point are the float numbers, and color is of boolean type (black or white).
I need to find a displacement vector `d = (d_x, d_y)`, which gives the best match to the sets. The cost function is the number of matched pairs. The pair is considered matched if both points have the same color, and L2 norm between the points is less than some epsilon.

What the algorithm solves my problem, what complexity it has?

Comment: Do you need the globally optimal solution? If not, you could try [ICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point).

Comment: Yes, the global one. But maybe suboptimal "in some meaning" at least.

Comment: Just re-read the question and noticed that you want to match points with the same color. Then I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate? What does `d` do? Can there be multiple points matched to a certain point?

Comment: Move all the points of set A by vector d. The resulting points must much the points of the set B. The total number of the matched points is the cost function. I need to find such d, that cost function be max.